# How to use Unmanaged Exports from C# in VBA?

Tags: c#, vba

I'm trying to export function from C# dll with Unmanaged Exports package (https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports). I don't want to use COM.

Unfortunatelly, I get an error:

> Can't find DLL entry point _TestDLL@4 in DllName

My C# class looks like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [DllExport]
    public static int TestDLL(int x)
    {
        return x + 2;
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
Private Declare Function TestDLL Lib "DllName" Alias "_TestDLL@4" (ByVal x As Long) As Long

Public Sub TestFunc()
    MsgBox CStr(TestDLL(2))
End Sub
```

Why wouldn't it work...?

Comment: Sounds like you simply didn't use the tool correctly, like not using the project template.  The Alias is not necessary, might as well remove it.  Double-check by running dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Hans Passant comment, I tried to use dumpbin.exe /exports on my dll, which gave an output:

> Dump of file DllName.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
> Section contains the following exports for \DllName.dll
>
> ```
> 00000000 characteristics
> 5315D2DA time date stamp Tue Mar 04 14:19:22 2014
>     0.00 version
>        1 ordinal base
>        1 number of functions
>        1 number of names
>
> ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>       1    0 000027DE TestDLL
> ```
>
> Summary
>
> ```
>     2000 .reloc
>     2000 .rsrc
>     2000 .sdata
>     2000 .text
> ```

As you can see, name of function is TestDLL. I corrected declaration in VBA to:

```
Private Declare Function TestDLL Lib "DllName" (ByVal x As Long) As Long
```

Now it works fine :)